# Users in Database

Tags: users

If I update my Drupal 7 Production site (20 user accounts) from my Development site (1 admin user account) will I lose all the user accounts in Production?

I'm just going to transfer the files and export/import the database from Development to Production.

Answer (score 2):

> will I lose all the user accounts in Production?

Depends.  If you replace the 'users' table, then yes, you will lose the accounts.  You can use the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to easily import your users.  That way you aren't overwriting the table itself.

Either way, backup, backup, backup!

Comment: Thanks, well I use the Backup and Migrate module and I figured it would replace everything. I cannot select tables to exclude. Could I use phpMyadmin and restore everything except the 'users table'?

Comment: I guess I could just export all DB tables except 'users' and 'user_roles' from DEV using phpMyAdmin and then Import only those tables into PROD?

Comment: Ah, Backup & Migrate DOES have the ability to Exclude specific tables...sweet! But as you said backup, backup, backup!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use phpmyadmin to export the users & users_roles tables from the production database and import them into the development database, then you can do your update as usual.

Note: I'm assuming there is no risk to any other data referencing uid since you are replacing everything else.